# Magento, Attribute with multiple fields

Tags: magento

I need for my shop to create an Attribute with multiple Fields.

For Example:

I create an attribute "select"

- Name (input)

Then I can define for each item 2 additional fields

- Description (textarea)
- Link (input)

In my product I select only the name.

Maybe some one has an idea?!